# Positivity for Hermitian dot product?

Tags: complex-numbers, inner-products, positive-definite

One of the requirements for the Hermitian dot product is positivity, i.e. $||v||^2 \ge 0, $ and $||v||^2 = 0 \iff v=0$. I was wondering what exactly this means in the complex numbers. Does it mean just the real part of the dot product must be positive, or that the imaginary part must also be 0?

Comment: what don't you understand in $\|v\|=0\iff v=0$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The positivity is about $h(x,x)$. In general, $h(x,y)$ is a complex number so it doesn't make sense to talk about positivity, but $h(x,x)$ is always a real number because of $h(y,x) = \overline{h(x,y)}$, so it makes sense to ask that it must be positive.

Comment: Ok, so if an inner product is defined in such a way that <x,x> results in a non-zero imaginary part, then it's not a (Hermitian) inner product?

Comment: Yes, because a hermitian inner product must satisfy the axiom I wrote in my question (in addition to sesquilinearity).